# jQuery DataTable - element class is removed after sort

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, datatable

I am developing a django app. In my HTML template I have a table, where one of the  is 2 rows of  that I am dynamically creating. This is the relevant td:

```
                             <td>
                                <div class="row">
                                    {% for d in p.get_list_of_lists %}
                                        <div class="a-box">{{ d.0 }}</div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                    {% for d in p.get_list_of_lists %}
                                        <div class="b-box">{{ d.1 }}</div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

I am running a javascript function on document ready to dynamically add class to each of the a-box:

```
function createSquares() {
    $('.a-box').each(function () {
        a= this.innerText
        switch (a) {
            case "1":
                $(this).addClass('great')
                break;
            case "2":
                $(this).addClass('good')
                break;
            case "3":
                $(this).addClass('ok')
                break;
            case "4":
                $(this).addClass('tough')
                break;
            case "5":
                $(this).addClass('bad')
                break;
            default:
            // code block
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code for the jQuery dataTable:

```
function createTable() {
    dt = $('#data')
    if (dt) {
        dt.DataTable({
            "order": [[3, "desc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': ['nosort']
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Everything is working well. I am able to color each box with the desired color. However, when I sort the table by one of its columns, some of the classes I added (great, good, ok, bad) are removed and some stay. I can't understand why and what is the difference between those who stay and those who don't.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Anyway I think you should call `createSquare()` function in `createTable()`, because sort redraw the table

Comment: Thanks. It is only a small part of the code so I can't post. I found the problem. The table is paginated and so only the cells on the first page are rendered with this class. Any idea on how to add the class to the other <td> that are not yet seen?

Comment: Sure, you have to create a function in `drawCallBack` option. Code in that function is executed on page changing event or, specifically, when the dataTable is redrawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by moving the createSquares into createTable like suggested above.

```
function createTable() {
    dt = $('#Data')
    if (dt) {
        dt.DataTable({
            "order": [[4, "desc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': ['nosort']
            }],
            "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                createFiveNext()
            }
        });
    }
}
```